# Laravel Validation: how to validate n days after date field 1?

Tags: validation, laravel-5.4

Is there a way to validate directly such that date field 2 is after n days of date field 1?

For example:

```
'date_1' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"',
'date_2' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"|after:date_1 +5 day'
```

I tried something like this but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

The after validation rule accepts date strings and they get converted using strtotime() php function. you can use carbon to play around with the date.

Assuming you are going to use this inside a class that extends FormRequest

`$new_date = Carbon::parse($this->date_1)->addDays(5);
 $new_date->toDateString();`

and then simply concat the value to the rule

`'date_2' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"|after:'.$new_date`

you can also create your own validation rules.
[laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation) have a pretty decent explanation on that.

Comment: instead, I used this `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data["date_1"]."+5 day"))`. However, in either case the error message will never say `after date_1` which it does when you just put an `after:date_1`

Comment: have you tried customizing the error message and passing what you want in there?

Comment: If ive to customise, I might just do the validation myself as well!